# Retrieving ITokenService from CRM Workflow context

Tags: authentication, token, workflow, crm

Currently i'm working on a CRM project. In this project i have to send data to web service. This operation must be work on custom workflow. In order to make web service call i need Authentication token, Currently i am trying to get ITokenService from CodeActivityContext, which is retrieving null, Any suggestions how to get ITokenService in workflow context?

```
>
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
{
    IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
    ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
    ITokenService TokenService = (ITokenService)executionContext.GetExtension<ITokenService>();
    if(TokenService == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Token service is null");
    serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId)

    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the overall objective, e.g. which service are you trying to call, why will ITokenService help?

Comment: It is Azure cloud service that i am trying to call, which need AADAccessToken for authentication header.